# Renaming columns in a MySQL select statement with R package RJDBC

Tags: mysql, r, jdbc

I am using the RJDBC package to connect to a MySQL (Maria DB) database in R on a Windows 7 machine and I am trying a statement like

```
select a as b
from table
```

but the column will always continue to be named "a" in the data frame.

This works normally with RODBC and RMySQL but doesn't work with RJDBC. Unfortunately, I have to use RJDBC as this is the only package that has no problem with the encoding of chinese, hebrew and so on letters (set names and so on don't seem to work with RODBC and RMySQL).

Has anybody experienced this problem?

Comment: I just tested it and can confirm the problem. Unfortunately I don't have a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have run into the same frustrating issue.  Sometimes the `AS` keyword would have its intended effect, but other times it wouldn't.  I was unable to identify the conditions to make it work correctly.

**Short Answer:** (Thanks to Simon Urbanek (package maintainer for RJDBC), Yev, and Sebastien!  See the **Long Answer.**)  One thing that you may try is to open your JDBC connection using `?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true` in your connection string.  Example:

```
drv <- JDBC("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "C:/JDBC/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar", identifier.quote="`")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:mysql://server/schema?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true", "username", "password")
query <- "SELECT `a` AS `b` FROM table"
result <- dbGetQuery(conn, query)
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

This ended up working for me!  See more details, including caveats, in the **Long Answer.**

**Long Answer:** I tried all sorts of stuff, including making views, changing queries, using JOIN statements, NOT using JOIN statements, using ORDER BY and GROUP BY statements, etc.  I was never able to figure out why some of my queries were able to rename columns and others weren't.

I contacted the package maintainer (Simon Urbanek.)  Here is what he said:

> In the vast majority of cases this is an issue in the JBDC driver, because there is really not much RJDBC can do other than to call the driver.

He then recommended that I make sure I had the most recent JDBC driver for MySQL. I did have the most recent version.  However, it got me thinking "maybe it IS a bug with the JDBC driver."  So, I searched Google for: `mysql jdbc driver bug alias`.

The top result for this query was [an entry at bugs.mysql.com](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33966).  Yev, using MySQL 5.1.22, says that when he upgraded from driver version 5.0.4 to 5.1.5, his column aliases stopped working.  Asked if it was a bug.

Sebastien replied, "No, it's not a bug!  It's a documented change of behavior in all subsequent versions of the driver." and suggested using `?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true`, citing [documentation for the JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

**Caveat Lector:**  The documentation for the JDBC driver states that

> useColumnNamesInFindColumn is preferred over useOldAliasMetadataBehavior unless you need the specific behavior that it provides with respect to ResultSetMetadata.

I haven't had the time to fully research what this means.  In other words, I don't know what all of the ramifications are of using `useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true` are.  Use at your own risk.  Does someone else have more information?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know RJDBC, but in some cases when it is necessary to give permanent aliases to columns without renaming them, you can use VIEWs

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_table AS
SELECT a AS b
FROM table
```

... and then ...

```
SELECT b FROM v_table
```

Comment: This is true, but would be not more than just a work around for the problem posted here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate function in the `ResultSetMetaData`  interface for retrieving the column *label* vs the column *name*:

```
String getColumnLabel(int column) throws SQLException;
```

> Gets the designated column's suggested title for use in printouts and
>   displays. The suggested title is usually specified by the SQL `AS`
>   clause.  If a SQL `AS` is not specified, the value returned
>   from`getColumnLabel` will be the same as the value returned by the
>   `getColumnName` method.

Using `getColumnLabel` should resolve this issue (if not, check that your JDBC driver is following this spec).

e.g.

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
while(rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++) {
        String label = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i);
        System.out.println(rs.getString(label));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the work around we use for R and SAP HANA via RJDBC:

`names(result)[1]<-"b"`

It's not the nicest work around, but since Aaron's solution does work for us, we went with this "solution".