# Select AS is not working properly with jdbc

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

I am using JTable to display the result of a query. Table does not show as `XYZ` for all  columns but it shows `XYZ` as a header for the fields not existing in database(manipulated fields).

Don't know much of database internals.Please forgive if it's too basic.

```
 rs1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT product.`id` as `Product ID`,product.`serialnumber` as `Serial Number`, product.`dop` as `Date Of Purchase` FROM product where product.`dop` between '"+from+"' and '"+to+"'");

         reportTable.setModel(buildTableModel(rs1));
```

same query on query browser Output:

```
Product ID    Serial Number     Date Of Purchase     
1              123244mf43m      08/08/2013
```

My Output With JDBC is:

```
id   serialnumber       dop      //table header
1    123244mf43m      08/08/2013
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703900/renaming-columns-in-a-mysql-select-statement-with-r-package-rjdbc

Comment: Hi davek,its MySql5.6 and Connector j 5.1.24.

Comment: What does `buildTableModel` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a configuration setting described here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

```
useOldAliasMetadataBehavior
```

which, if set to true (the default in 5.0.x) will only return aliases (if any) for ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName() or ResultSetMetaData.getTableName() rather than the original column/table name.

Not sure if this is applicable to you, but could be the cause.

Comment: It Worked For me.. Thanks a lot for quick help.Thank you very much.

Comment: It is more a bug of whatever `buildTableModel` does.